# jquery class toggle variables: unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery

Quick note: Not sure why I can't find this question addressed on SO/elsewhere. Hope it's not a dupe.

***Question***: how do I pass *at least* two classes as variables to jQuery for a toggleClass?

In this simplistic snippet, it works perfectly if I use the classnames

```js
var varRed = "red", varUpper = "upper";
$("#test").on("click", function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('red upper');
});
```

```css
.red{color: red;}
.upper{text-transform: capitalize;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">class toggle</div>
```

How do I obtain the equivalent of `$(this).toggleClass('red upper');` with variables such as?

```
$(this).toggleClass(varRed varUpper);
```

The latter throws an error.

Obviously one could do:

`$(this).toggleClass(varRed).toggleClass(varUpper);`

but I am trying to understand why .toggleClass('red upper') works and toggleClass(varRed varUpper) does not.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass(varRed + ' ' + varUpper);` ... _toggleClass(varRed varUpper) does not_ That's how string concatenation (what this comes down to) works in js

Comment: Thank you. This is what I suspected. To be clear, is this a workaround or just the *the* way to deal with such situations?

Comment: That's just string concatenation, yes - not a workaround. You could also pass an array though, that's maybe the nicer syntax `toggleClass([varRed, varUpper])`

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it and hopefully others will stumble upon it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use

```
$(this).toggleClass(varRed + ' ' + varUpper);
```

> but I am trying to understand why .toggleClass('red upper') works and
>   toggleClass(varRed varUpper) does not.

That's how you concatenate two strings in JavaScript, which is what you are basically trying to do.

You could also pass an array though, which is possibly the nicer syntax

```
$(this).toggleClass([varRed, varUpper])
```

Comment: Ah! The array answer is perfect. Much nicer to read. Thank you again